Characterizing rational functions satisfying some properties
We have that $\nu(x)$
for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ is a rational function which is characterized by ($\nu(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$):

$\nu(x) \geq 0$;
$0 \leq q(x)-p(x)$;
$q(x)$ has non-real roots.

Moreover, $\nu(x):=\text{Im}(h(x))$ for some rational analytic function  $h$ that satisfies: $$h:\mathbb{H}:=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:\text{Im}(z)>0\}\to \mathbb{H}\cup \mathbb{R}.$$
I wonder if there is any other way I could characterize $\nu(x)$, perhaps in terms of the residue of $h$ or directly in the above definition.
Edit: I was asked to add some context here it is. We begin by considering any analytic function $N(z):\mathbb{H}\to \overline{\mathbb{H}}.$ Note here that we do not require that $N$ is rational, which we do with $h$ above. The goal is to characterize all such functions which are rational, i.e. functions like $h$. Such functions have an integral representation: $$N(z)=a+bz+\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{1}{\lambda-z}-\frac{\lambda}{\lambda^2+1}\right)d\mu(\lambda)$$
where $a$ is a real constant, $b$ is a non-negative constant and  $\mu$ is a positive Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the growth condition $$\int_{R}\frac{1}{\lambda^2+1}d\mu(\lambda)<\infty.$$ More is contained in the Wikipedia article.
The goal then is to characterize rational $N$ by characterizing its corresponding measure $\mu$. The case when $N$ is rational and meromohpic on the real line is straight forward, the corresponding measure is a discrete measure, i.e. it is a sum of Dirac measures. I am interested in the case when $N$ is rational and meromorphic in the lower half-plane, $\text{Im}[z]<0.$ It can be shown that in such cases, the measure is absolutely continuous and moreover the Radon-Nikodym derivative with respect to the Lebesgue measure is given by $d\mu=k(x)d\lambda$ where $$k(x)=\text{Im}[N(x+i\cdot0)].$$ I claim that $N(z)$ is rational with poles in the lower half-plane if and only if the corresponding measure is absolutely continuous and $k(x)$ satisfies the three conditions above. The is is the background to the question, we have that $h(z)$ is analytic, rational and maps the upper half-plane to the upper half-planet plus the real line, which I claim is equivalent to $\nu(x)$ (defined above) satisfying conditions 1 to 3.
I was wondering then if there is an easier way to simplify this.

The polynomial $q(x)$ has no poles. Edit your post changing $q(x)$ by you know

Thank, meant roots.

what is the problem you are interested in to use the new characterization you want - as of now this is very vague

I added additional comments, hope this clarifies my questions. You are welcome to ask if you have any questions.
